# Removing the Top bar in Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: gnome, files, syslinux

So to go further into detail I have a screenshot of my desktop right [image]

what I need help with is removing the whole bar on the top including the battery the wifi the tabs the little activities bar completely.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.panel.hide();'
```

above command hides the bar so that if you need to call back, you can do so with below command

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.panel.show();'
```

You can destroy the panel such that you cant call back,

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.panel.destroy();'
```

All the above commands will revert back once you relogin. To make any of the command to be persistent, need to add the command you required in startup command list.

Comment: This helped a lot do you know how to delete the wifi or time or activities icons/bars?

Comment: you mean individually?

Comment: Yes so how i could remove the time individual or completely wipe the bar so its just the black bar going across.

Comment: Oh, thats clear. I will workout now. Be online for few minutes.

Comment: `gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.panel.remove_all_children();'`

Comment: thanks you so much and I know i'm asking for a lot but is there a way to do this through a GUI

Comment: that is not provided by GNOME, I mean the GUI way. But It can be managed through extensions. I mean need to write one for your need case.

Comment: Thanks a lot man :)

Comment: You try gnome extension "just perfection" in that you will have toggle buttons for your need case..